# Understanding the proof of Theorem 9.4 in Montgomery & Vaughan's Multiplicative Number Theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, modular-arithmetic, characters

The following is from "Multiplicative number theory I: Classical theory" by Hugh L. Montgomery, Robert C. Vaughan:

[image]

I understand everything in the proof except for:

How existence of $c$ such that $(c,q)=1$ and $cm \equiv n$ (mod $q$) is guaranteed?

Comment: [Here is why you should not use images to convey critical information not otherwise present in your post.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\chi(mn)\ne0$, we have $(mn,q)=1$ and hence $(m,q)=1$. Therefore one can choose $c\equiv m^{-1}n$ (mod $q$) to obtain $cm\equiv n$ (mod $q$).

Comment: How $(c,q)=1$ then?

Comment: The product of two reduced residue classes (mod $q$) is always another reduced residue class (mod $q$). This shows the importance of having a solid foundation in elementary number theory/modular arithmetic when moving forward to more advanced fields.

Comment: I have studied a lot for elementary number theory, I couldn't get the result I think because of high anxiety I feel for I have just started my PhD and my mind freezes